# How to delete BT Content Slider's article first-letter blank space?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, css

I want to delete in Joomla this kind of first-letter blank space but don't know how. (its marked with a red circle)

[image]

Comment: It appears to be part of the markup and not CSS related. I would check your content to make sure you haven't accidentally added spaces before the sentence

Answer (score 1):

This blank space comes from your empty paragraph lines in the article markup:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Remove them from your article and the white space should be gone because I assume that the BT Content Slider stripps of the HTML and just leaves the `&nbsp;` which is a white space.

To remove them just remove the empty line or switch to the code view and remove the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` tag under the image.

You should consider giving your `<p>` tags a bottom margin with CSS. At the moment you are making margins under each paragraph with an empty paragraph which isn't a good practice (and now you see why)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `&nbsp;` in the text of your articles, after the image and just before the actual text. Examining the full article, I found the same structure, apart the fact that everything is wrapped inside `<p>` tags.

I suspect that the module fetches the introtext of your articles, stripping out some html tags - in this case the `<p>` element, therefore it ends ups showing the image, the `&nbsp;`- which is not a html tag, and the text that follows.

**Some options you have:**

1. Check if the module has any settings on how to handle the html entities and adjust it.
2. Remove the new lines through creating emtpy paragraphs, and add the required space by adjusting the css of your paragraphs.
3. If you are using the introtext feature, but you aren't showing anywhere else in your site those articles in a blog view, which usually makes use of the introtext, you could just have the introtext without the `&nbsp;` - only the image and the actual text, to satisfy the module and then in the fulltext area, repeat your introtext, using your current content structure.
4. See if using the images section of the article's instead of placing images inside the introtext can give you more flexibility/options.
5. Override the module's output, and manipulate the actual content by removing the non-breaking space html entity.

Something like this over the echoed content could work:

```
$ html = "articles_introtext"; // sample var of what it comes out as the article introtext.

echo "<div>" . html_entity_decode( strip_tags( str_replace( "&nbsp;", "", $html ) ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' ) ."</div>";
```

The above may be used in combination.